# Import javascript in php

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

How can i import javascript in php? No matter what i try, i can't seem to get the buttons in my page to trigger the events in javascript.

This is my javascript file content:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

 var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

 for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

  var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

  newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  //alert(newcell.childNodes);
  switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
   case "text":
     newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
     break;
   case "checkbox":
     newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
     break;
   case "select-one":
     newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
     break;
  }
 }
}
```

and

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
 try {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;

 for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
  var row = table.rows[i];
  var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
  if(null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
   if(rowCount <= 1) {
    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
    break;
   }
   table.deleteRow(i);
   rowCount--;
   i--;
  }

 }
 }catch(e) {
  alert(e);
 }
}
```

This is how i try to import it in a php file:

```
       <HEAD>
 <script src="myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</HEAD>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is perfectly all right. Is the file getting loaded? What are you expecting to happen that doesn't happen?

Comment: this doesnt seem to be a PHP problem at all

Comment: How can i see if the file is getting loaded? When i look in the source code in the webbrowser, i can see the script tag. What i'm expecting is a row being added after pressing the button 'addrow'. See this example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript.html

Comment: maybe the js path of the file is not in the same directory ?!

Comment: can you show your html code including the btton for add row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up the page in Firefox. Right click the page and select the option to show the sourcecode. Find the script tag and click the linked src. If it gives you a 404, the link is wrong. If it shows your JS code, it's fine. Install Firebug for Firefox and debug your code with it. Make sure your Event Listeners actually get triggered.

Comment: Hi, i found it! it had to do with the path. i had to go back a few directories and then tell it where the js file is located some thing like this: ../../application/view/myfile.js

Comment: @Yustme instead of a relative path, you can use an absolute path. Absolute Paths are relative to the Document Root. Try changing the path to `/application/view/myfile.js`. This should save you fiddling with directory traversal.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your src attribute is pointing to the correct location of the JS file.
(maybe it needs to be "/myfile.js" if the JS file is located under your document root, but the php file isn't).

Comment: The "src" takes a URL, absolute or relative. How that maps onto the file system on your server is entirely determined by your webserver configuration: a full (file) path is almost certainly not going to work. 

You need to check whether the file is actually being loaded, as others have said, and if not, work out how you need to specify the src to satisfy your server's configuration. (It might also be a file permission issue on your server).